# How to: Provide component with innerBlocks to Wordpress Gutenberg's save function?

Tags: block-editor

What I have:

- I have a UI-kit written as React library and tailwind.
- Each element in this UI-kit uses a functional approach and hooks.
- Every component has logic that depends on props (which I convert to attributes).

and the problem is that I cannot reuse these components inside the save function of Gutenberg due to the constraints of this function. (save function can't use components/function that has side effects like hooks)

so, in the first case where I've needed to just re-use my component I used this approach:

```
export default function save({attributes}) {
     const {text , variant} = attributes;
     return (
         <> 
            {parseHTML(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                <Button variant={variant}>
                    <RichText.Content value={text}/>
                </Button>
            ))}
         </>
     );
 }
```

1. Convert component and its subcomponents to string using react-dom/server
2. Convert that string into a single react component using [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser)
3. Provide this component to save function

And it worked perfectly so far I didn't need to use InnerBlocks for nested blocks:

```
const save = ({attributes})  => {
    return (
        <div>
            {parseHTML(
                ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                    <Wrapper>
                        <InnerBlocks.Content/> 
                    </Wrapper>
                )
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

and the error:

```
index.js:5130 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Component(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
at validateRenderResult (index.js:5130)
at processChild (index.js:5254)
at resolve (index.js:5150)
at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (index.js:5633)
at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (index.js:5570)
at Object.renderToString (index.js:6178)
at save (index.js:7448)
at getSaveElement (blocks.js:9166)
at getSaveContent (blocks.js:9213)
at addParsedDifference (block-editor.js:14707)
```

---

**UPD: example of component from UI library**

```
import React , {useMemo} from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
const DefaultButton = ({className, rounded, ...props}) => {

    const classes = useMemo(() => clsx([
        className,
        "shroud-px-6 shroud-py-3",
        "shroud-font-bold shroud-text-white",
        "shroud-bg-white shroud-bg-secondary-100 hover:shroud-bg-primary-100",{
            "shroud-rounded-full": rounded,
        }
    ]) , [className]);


    return <button className={classes} {...props} />
};

export default DefaultButton;
```

Comment: components in a save function should not need side effects, they return static HTML for saving, and any values they need come from attributes. Set those attributes in your edit component. A save component with local state and side effects makes no sense.

Comment: Also you shouldn't need to stringify/serialize those components, the editor is supposed to do that for you. Isn't the `parseHTML( ReactDOMServer.renderToString(` a non-operation? E.g. `return json_decode( json_encode( $foo ) );`? Simplify it to  `return $foo`

Comment: @TomJNowell I understand that the save function must contain pure component without any side effect (like hooks) but i need to use one to reuse my ui-kit library written in react.
It uses useMemo hook to cache classname (clsx to be percise). 

To use this kind of functionality inside save function i used parseHTML that create react component from string and ReactDomServer to transform my component into string.
In this way any component that uses hooks or anything like that will be transformed into pure component without any side effects

Comment: Why can't you take the output from clsx and store it as an attribute in your edit component? A block should be able to generate the save output using only the attributes declared

Comment: @TomJNowell Because in this case, I will be forced to rewrite the entire library by hand.
Also, this UI library is an external package that could update in the future and I don't want to re-write my whole plugin after each update of this external library.

Comment: @TomJNowell UPD: provided example of the component from ui library. 
I've edited this component a little bit just to show you that almost each component in this library uses useMemo hook to cache clsx( analogue of classnames).

Comment: Just to summarize: only problem that im facing right now is that i cant provide <InnerBlocks.Content> to ReactDOMServer.renderToString() and convert it to string.
I'm totally sure that it is the wrong usage of InnerBlocks.Content.

Comment: Why are you using `useMemo` to cache `clsx`? I don't see the benefit and I can theorise problems, those aren't expensive functions

Comment: if your components HTML class name props are changing many thousands of times a second I could understand this, but then that just means you're plastering over a different much bigger problem, and if `className` changes you'd need to re-run `clsx` anyway so I don't understand how you're making any performance savings? The fix to this problem ( and several others you probably haven't realised ), is to remove `useMemo`. The component is only re-rendered when the props change or it's loaded/unloaded, at which time you'd need to recalculate this anyway

Comment: I am not responsible for this library. As far as I understand, this is done because in 99% of cases the class names will not change from the moment the component is mounted into the tree.

Comment: If the class names/props don't change then the components don't get re-rendered. The solution you've tried to devise with `ReactDOMServer` is a dead end as those inner components would need state they do not have access to. What you want cannot be done, either the library needs to be fixed ( dev who is responsible has misunderstood how components are rendered ), or you need to use a different library. `useMemo` cannot be used, there is no workaround that preserves `useMemo` use, and the usage of `useMemo` you are trying to preserve is incorrect

Comment: btw if this UI-kit has a name, options may open up that were previously unavailable

Comment: I am also don't why they are using  useMemo hook to rembember clsx  result as i think clsx under the hood using caching too but I cannot do anything about this.

This ui-kit was created for a specific project and does not open for public use

Comment: `clsx` doesn't depend on React, it's an ultra tiny library with only dev dependencies https://github.com/lukeed/clsx/blob/master/src/index.js, using `useMemo` with clsx is equivalent to using it on a bunch of if else statements in a loop, it's even possible that a cached `useMemo` itself is slower than `clsx`. You can safely remove `useMemo` in all places that it wraps `clsx` without worrying, it may even speed up the library. btw what was the error you encountered by using `useMemo` directly without any of the workarounds you tried?